# __MonoCS__ constant equivalent in Mono, Roslyn, Dnvm

Tags: c#, mono, roslyn, dnvm

I have imports, that does not work well in Mono (even on compile time!), in my C# project. I want to exclude some code in Mono (in compile time). I've used something similar before:

```
#if !__MonoCS__
...
#endif
```

However this constant is not defined in Mono 4.0.2, OSX. Probably only on DNVM or Roslyn.

If I define the **__MonoCS__** constant manually in the beginning of the file. Everything works fine.

Is there any **__MonoCS__** equivalent on this platform?

---

*If this matter, my project is asp.net vnext based webapi. And I run the project with the following command:*

```
/Users/buraktamturk/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-beta4/bin/dnx . kestrel
```

---

For many specific information, the answer of "why i need it in compile time?". The project only working when the following code is commented out.

```
if(false) { // yes, false!
  var certificate = new X509Certificate2(config.Get("google:pkeyloc"), config.Get("google:pkeypw"), X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

   credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
              new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(config.Get("google:serviceacc"))
              {
                  Scopes = new[] { StorageService.Scope.DevstorageFullControl }
              }.FromCertificate(certificate)
    );
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I get "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Net.Http'" when the following code is active. However, I use System.Net.Http almost every part of the project without any problem.

Comment: Also Console.WriteLine("Hello World"); before the if(false) does not work if i do not exclude the code too.

Comment: That error comes from the JITter, as it tries to JIT-compile your function.  See my answer.

Comment: Or, try to get that DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move that code to a different function.

As long as you don't call that function on platforms that don't have that DLL, everything will be fine.

Comment: WOW! It is not the answer of the question but it solved my problem, I did something like ````if(!isMono) { test1234(); }````and it worked!